# Android Web Service Implememnation

Tags: android, web-services

```
package com.login.android;

import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;

import com.login.android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class login extends Activity {
    // Declare our Views, so we can access them later
    private EditText etUsername;
    private EditText etPassword;
    private Button btnLogin;
    private Button btnCancel;
    private TextView lblResult;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set Activity Layout
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Get the EditText and Button References
        etUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        etPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        btnCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
        lblResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

        // Set Click Listener
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Check Login
                SocketChannel sock = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress("www.abcd.com", 80));

                String data = etUsername + "|" + etPassword;
                sock.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(data.getBytes()));

                ByteBuffer result = ByteBuffer.allocate(8); // 8 byte-large container for result
                fSocket.read(result);

                if (result.get(0) == 1)
                         {
                                          lblResult.setText("Login successful.");

                    } else {

                                   lblResult.setText("Login failed. Username and or password doesn't match.");
                }
            }
            });

        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Close the application
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I run this I get `fSocket` error. `FSocket cannot be resolved`. Kindly tell me what is the mistake I have made here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you declare the fSocket variable ?

Comment: It was a mistake. Since we used "sock", Use that to call!! no fSocket, its sock.read(result); i have wrongly used fSocket.